# Understanding the graphite response (datapoint) for a summarize query for last 24 hours

Tags: graphite

**Request:**

```
http://example.com:8081/render?format=json&target=summarize(stats.development.com.xxx.operation.yyy.*.*.rate, "24hours", "sum", true)&from=-24hours&tz=UTC
```

**Response:**

> [{"datapoints":[[0.1,1386198900]],"target":"summarize(stats.development.com.xxx.operation.yyy.5.4.rate,
>   "24hours", "sum", true)"}]

What I wanted was the summary of last 24hours for the stat provided in query.

- Can you please interpret "datapoint" for me?
- What does "0.1" mean? What is its logarithmic scale?
- What does 1386198900 mean?

Comment: Please provide pointers to any documentation that can help understand graphite response/datapoints.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphite returning incorrect datapoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433697/graphite-returning-incorrect-datapoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{
  "datapoints" : 
              [[0.1,1386198900]], 
  "target":
              "summarize(stats.development.com.xxx.operation.yyy.5.4.rate, "24hours", "sum", true)"
}]
```

Here, `datapoints` sent to the metric `stats.development.com.xxx.operation.yyy.5.4.rate`, when numerically summed on a 24 hour basis, is `0.1` for the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) `1386198900`, which is the system's way of saying `Wed, 04 Dec 2013 23:15:00 GMT`. The logarithmic scale is not involved here.

Consider the following example-

You create a metric- `website.about-us-page.hits` and start sending data every 10 seconds-

```
1386198900: 3
1386198910: 23
1386198920: 12
1386198930: 1
1386198940: 0
1386198950: 180
1386198960: 12
```

This URL API request to graphite-
`target=summarize(stats.website.about-us-page.hits, "20seconds", "sum", true)`  will return something like-

```
[{
  "datapoints" : 
              [[26,1386198900]], // sum of first two points
              [[13,1386198920]], // sum of next two points
              [[180,1386198940]],
              [[12,1386198960]], 
  "target":
              "summarize(stats.website.about-us-page.hits, "20seconds", "sum", true)"
}]
```

`summarize()` basically helps you see the data in different granularity. Like in cases when you need to know day-wise or hour-wise traffic, rather than on a 10s basis.

Comment: Understand that syntactically, graphite is 'unit' agnostic. The unit is semantically determined. As in, if you are sending the `number of potatoes` that you plucked everyday, then 10 on the graph implies the pure number. If you are sending `kilograms of potatoes you plucked`, then *that* becomes the unit. If you are sending `millions of tonnes shipped everyday` then *that* becomes the unit. Usually, the time() functions in most languages return values in milliseconds and hence 10K on the graph means 10 seconds.